# why does my (ubuntu 11.10 bash 4.2.10, x86_64 ) named pipe get clogged?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, named-pipes

Step 1: I open a terminal and type

```
mkfifo mypipe
cat < mypipe
```

Step 2: I open another and type:

```
for elem in {1..100} ; do echo "$elem" > mypipe ; done
```

A random ammount of numbers get printed, the **first script exits** and **the second hangs**. 
Please share the wizdom. Ubuntu bug? If more info is needed please ask, i don't imagine anything relevant atm.

Thx,
you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way named pipes work is that when the writing process closes the pipe, the reading process receives an EOF. When `cat` sees the file has ended it stops reading and exits. Here bash seems to reuse the open file most of the time in the loop, rather than closing and reopening it in each run.

To ensure that the file is opened and closed exactly once you could write this:

```
(for elem in {1..100} ; do echo "$elem"  ; done) > mypipe
```

To get `cat` output exactly one number in each run you have to use the program `/bin/echo` rather than the built-in `echo`. This forces Bash to open and close the file in each run of the loop:

```
for elem in {1..100} ; do /bin/echo "$elem" > mypipe ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's a bug, it's that the `cat` side prints more than one. It's a race condition. What's happening there is that the `cat` is reading one line, before it can read the EOF afterwards (because they're separate writes) the `echo` writes the next line, so `cat` gets that, etc. Eventually, it seems, `cat` reaches an EOF before the `echo` redirect can write to the pipe. If you want to write all the numbers to the pipe at once, move the redirect to the end:

```
for elem in {1..100} ; do echo "$elem" done > mypipe
```

Or better,

```
seq 100 > mypipe
```

If you want `cat` to get only one at a time... I'm not quite sure how you can do that easily (Though I believe I could hack it if necessary).